# Java (Brute-Force Application) supported by multiple Nodes (Computers on network)

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, cluster-computing

OK, I think question is pretty simple. This is only for testing on University. I would like to brute-force attack some password (not to complicate, just to find given string by brute-forcing). It's basically one loooong for loop combination that could be performed in new thread. Is there any way to distribute that "thread" over computers on same network? Use multiple computers (for example in electronical class - with 100 computers) just to support  with their processing power that same for loop (thread). And all resolts are displayed on that computer where program started (some kind of master or server computer).

Is something like that possible in Java? Windows 7 is operating system.

Comment: Are you asking use to do your assignment? Yes, it is possible. If that is your only question.

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/ is a popular choice for this sort of problem.

Comment: Are you supposed to code everything from scratch (university exercise) or you can use any infrastructure you want ? (as @PeterLawrey suggested)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to build the application yourself instead of using a framework, I recommend, you take a walk through the RMI Trail: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/

I did a simple distributed computing engine myself some time ago, and it turned out to be pretty easy using RMI.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. You need to have a master/controller computer and several worker computers or slaves. The master breaks the problem into chunks and allocates chunks to slaves. The slaves perform chunks of work and report back to the master when they have finished.

The most complicated part is getting the master/slaves to talk to each other. A relatively simple solution would be to use sockets and invent some trivial comms protocol.

The master algorithm would look something like;

```
break problem into chunks
while problem not solved {
  wait for socket comms from slave
  if slave is asking for a chunk of work
    allocate chunk to slave
  else if slave is reporting a chunk didn't contain the solution
    mark chunk as completed
    allocate chunk to slave
  else if slave is reporting a chunk did contain the solution
    problem is solved
}
```

The slave algorithm would look something like;

```
while problem not solved {
  ask master for a chunk of work
  process this chunk
  if chunk contains solution
    problem is solved
  report results back to master
}
```

You need to make your chunk size big enough so that the slaves spend most of their time solving the problem and not talking to the master. The frequency at which slaves talk to the master will probably determine the number of slaves a single master is able to handle. At a first guess I'd say size the chunks so that a slave takes 2 or 3 minutes to process it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answers. I can use anything already made, I don't need to code that part. Problem is, there are no multiple little problems so I could distribute them to other clusters and wait for them to solve them... There is ONLY ONE LONG LOOP, one LONG FOR LOOP that I would like to SPEED UP using processing power of multiple computers in same local network.

I'm thinking that should be some tool that is connecting Java Virtual Machines, not software I wrote alone. Somehow, that's the only way I see solution for this.